# В библиотеку / На дискотеку

Tags: предлоги

Почему существительное дискотека употребляется с предлогами на/с, а не в/из по аналогии с библиотека и аптека? 54:52 [в дискотеку](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q31SlWh-sZ0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут важна семантика имени существительного.
Если оно называет территорию с определенными службами или место деятельности без представления о помещении (завод, фабрика, вокзал, почта, кафедра, выставка, курорт), различного рода трудовые процессы, занятия (спектакль, состязания, работа, **дискотека**), употребляется предлог **на** , в остальных случаях – предлог **в** (аудитория, цех, аптека, **библиотека**).

1. Есть "запоминалка".
   **НА** воле и **В** неволе: все, без "ограничения" — **НА**; с оным — **В**.
2. Есть простое правило.
   В современном русском литературном языке предлоги **ИЗ** и **С** имеют антонимы (т. е. противоположные по значению предлоги).
   Для **ИЗ** — это предлог **В**, а для **С** — предлог **НА**.
   По этим парам легко установить правильное употребление предлогов или проверить себя в затруднительных случаях.

**Из** библиотеки — **в** библиотеку; **с** дискотеки — **на** дискотеку.

[С завода, но ИЗ дома](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=13.8)

Answer (score 0):

Пойти **на дискотеку.**

Здесь ***дискотека*** — это мероприятие (отвлеченное существительное), поэтому используется предлог НА. Сравнить: *пойти на лекцию в институт, пойти на концерт в консерваторию.*

**ДИСКОТЕКА**, 3. Увеселительное собрание, вечер, на котором прослушивают грамзаписи и танцуют под них.